# Short-Circuit If Condition Does not work

Tags: c#, exception, nullreferenceexception

I have a code segment that throws an NullReferenceException. The code segment is like this.

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.FirstName) && !(user.FirstName.Length <= 64))
{
    // Some Code
}
```

Here the if condition first should check if `user.FirstName` is Null or WhiteSpace. When the value of `user.FirstName` is null this code segment throws a `NullReferenceException`. I assume that this is thrown by checking the `Length` of `user.FirstName`, but since this is a short-circuit check shouldn't the first expression satisfy the condition and execute the code inside the if block. Or am i missing something here.

Comment: What is your primary problem. That the second criterium is not being called or that a criterium throws a NullReferenceException, which you did not expect?

Comment: I think the question is unclear and the OP is not responding.

Comment: I realized the stupid mistake i have made here in understanding how this works. The short-circuit check works fine. What i missed was that IsNullorWhiteSpace returns true when the property is null. A silly mistake cost me a fair amount of rep. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you can have TWO different causes for the `NullReferenceException`:

```
- Value `user` is null;
- `user.FirstName` is null.
```

I assume you've checked already if `user` is not null, so lets skip that one.

Now lets assume that `user.FirstName` is null, what happens then?

The first condition `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.FirstName)` will result to `true`. Is this enough for the if-statement to execute the inner code block or should the second condition also be evaluated?

Lets take a look at this truth-table:

```
A  && B     = RESULT
--------------------
False False = False
False True  = False
True  False = False
True  True  = True
```

So when using the `&&`-operator the total condition is only true when both subconditions are true. So when the first condition is true, the second one still needs to be evaluated. A simple translation of the truth-table according to C# would be (where ??? stands for: Don't care):

```
A  && B     = RESULT
--------------------
False ???   = False
True  False = False
True  True  = True
```

So when checking your second condition, the property `user.FirstName.Length` is read, resulting in your `NullReferenceException`.

How to prevent this. As other people have stated, you probably want to execute the code block when: The `FirstName` is NULL *OR* Empty *OR* WhiteSpace *OR* larger than 64. Your current condition checks, basically, if FirstName is NULL *AND* larger than 64.

So... use the ||-operator:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.FirstName) || !(user.FirstName.Length <= 64))
```

or more clear:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.FirstName) || (user.FirstName.Length > 64))
```

The C# truth-table would be:

```
A  || B     = RESULT
--------------------
False False = False
False True  = True
True  ???   = True
```

In which you can cleary see the "short circuit" part.

Answer (score 5):

The second part is only executed when

```
string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.FirstName)
```

results in true. So you need

```
!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.FirstName) && !(user.FirstName.Length <= 64)
```

or

```
string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.FirstName) || !(user.FirstName.Length <= 64)
```

depending on your requirements. Also, `user` could be `null` in which case the short-circuiting won't help at all.

Answer (score 2):

Before posting *doesn't* work assertions let's analyze your problem 
(C# solutions contain *billion lines of code*: do you really think that
such a common construction as `if` can be able not to work?)

It seems that you want to check if user's name is *invalid* one:

1. if user name is null or empty or white space
2. or if it's too long (more than 64 character)

the implementation is quite clear now:

```
  const int USER_NAME_MAX_LENGTH = 64;

  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.FirstName) || 
      user.FirstName.Length > USER_NAME_MAX_LENGTH) {
    // user name is invalid
    ...   
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`&&` doesn't short circuit as you expect it to, it's quite the opposite.

It needs to check both conditions if the first one is true, and only if both are true it'll execute the block inside: if the first condition is true (i.e, `user.FirstName` is null) then it needs to check whether the second one is true aswell, thus your exception (since `user.FirstName` will always be null -unless it's empty or whitespace- when checking its `Length`).

**Edit**: since the above paragraph seems not to be clear for some people: I'm not saying `&&` doesn't short-circuit (it'd short-circuit if the first condition was `false`), I'm saying it doesn't short-circuit as expected by the OP

Comment: Care to explain the downvoting?

Comment: Although your answer is technically correct, it does not have any bearing on the problem. It does not matter if operator && checks only one or both criteria, the problem is about `user` being null.

Comment: @MartinMulder it seems the OP is asking why it doesn't short-circuit so I tried to explain *that*

Comment: Or i understand that from: `but since this is a short-circuit check shouldn't the first expression satisfy the condition and execute the code inside the if block. Or am i missing something here.`

Comment: I asked him to clearify his question. Lets see what happens.

Comment: @MartinMulder Taking the title of the question and the content, I'd say the confusion (for the OP) is clear... but taking the 3 downvotes I got it seems it's only clear to me :-)

Comment: I'd say that the downvotes are because the `&&` operator _does_ short circuit (if the first operand is false), which at first glance you seem to be contradicting.  Yes, the OP's code is broken,  but your explanation of this is somewhat unclear.

Comment: @Corey I never said it didn't short-circuit, I said "it doesn't short-circuit as the op is expecting it to". The more I reread my question I don't see anything wrong or unclear on it (and I'd say I know what I'm talking about when doing C#), I think it's clear, and it explains the OP's confusion... but that's ok, I'll take the downvotes: I stand by my answer anyway.

Comment: @Jcl Which *at first glance* you *seem* to be contradicting.  For a lot of people as soon as they read the first line they will assume that you are saying "&& doesn't short circuit" which is incorrect, and downvotes will immediately follow.  That's all I was trying to point out.

Comment: @Corey note taken, I've added a clearification paragraph

Comment: Clear or not, my impression is that the OP had a problem, started to solve it by going the wrong direction. He did not succeed and thats why he asked the question. But his question is partly based on his wrong direction which results in a question existing of two parts: The original problem and the newly created problem. In my opinion. That why I asked the OP for clearification.